# Use Reddit API to access front page data on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xpath, reddit

How do you use the reddit API to get the title/upvotes/op of a post using IOS? Is it even possible or do I have to parse the HTML? I have already parsed the front page but the posts I get don't match the desktop version at all. I feel there must be an easier way to access this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sort of answered this yourself. Use the [Reddit API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api), request the information you want and parse the JSON that's returned from the API. Specific community support found [here](http://reddit.com/r/redditdev) but be sure to try and solve your problems by searching first.

You'll find a wealth of information on parsing [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) on StackOverflow, including examples specific to your language.

You can easily get the front page JSON by requesting: http://reddit.com/.json to start with.